# Auto Submit a Form in a period of time

Tags: javascript

I got this auto form submitter as I search the internet. Though I want it to execute the submission in a certain period of time. Like perhaps after 5 or 10 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formAutoSubmit () {
var frm = document.getElementById("31926767765874");
frm.submit();
}
setTimeout(function() { formAutoSubmit(); } , 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run after 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() { formAutoSubmit(); } , 5000);
```

If you want to run it each 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() { formAutoSubmit(); } , 5000);
```

Comment: So just remove `window.onload = formAutoSubmit;`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look, and read up on, [JavasScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). You can simply wrap `formAutoSubmit()` in a timer, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formAutoSubmit() {
    var frm = document.getElementById("31926767765874");
    frm.submit();
}

var timeout = 2000; //2 seconds or 2000 ms
setTimeout(function() 
{ 
    formAutoSubmit(); 
}, timeout);
</script>
```

Caveat: this can be a nuisance for the user experience, so tread carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(formAutoSubmit, 10000);
```

That's 10000 ms (or 10s)